# Fetching child elements of parent using velocity code

Tags: liferay, liferay-velocity

I am keeping Asia as a parent element. Under that, I am keeping India and China as child elements. I want to fetch both of the countries by using velocity code.

Below is my code: I am using the method `getChildren()` and I am getting only the first child and am unable to get its two children.

I have parent element as `continent` and child elements as `countries`.

```
#foreach ($cur_continent in $continent.getSiblings())
#foreach($countries in $cur_continent.getChildren())
$countries.getData()
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please clarify your question; what exactly are you asking and what have you tried?

Comment: Is mentioned code here is complete? You are missing `#end`  for `#foreach`

Answer (score 0):

- What's the error message that you're getting - e.g. in the logfile?
- As Pankaj mentions in the comments: make sure that you have an `#end` for every `#foreach`
- If you want to know which methods you can call on each element, you can assume that they're java objects: Start with just writing $continent.getClass().getName(), see the result and look up the Java interface, so that you know what to call on each object.
- Note that you use `getSiblings` and `getChildren` - probably expecting to have the same/similar results?

Once you went through this checklist, let us know what you found

Edit: Unfortunately the javadoc for `com.liferay.portal.kernel.templateparser.TemplateNode` isn't yet there, however, there's a difference between `getSiblings` and `getChildren`, and I'm always mixing them up - try both, alternatively, and let us know if one works. Currently you're using both at the same time (in different instructions). I believe that one of them will do what you want.

Comment: Hi Kock Thanks for your response. Here my code contained  #end also and i am not getting any error. My problem here is when i am using getChildren i am only getting the first child element(india) instead of getting all the childs(india,China).

Comment: Any one please help me on the above issue.

Comment: so, did you follow the suggestions that I gave? What's the result of $cur_continent.getClass().getName()? What's the interface of that class's getChildren() function? How does it differ from getSiblings()?

Comment: Yes i followed your instructions. The interface name is com.liferay.portal.kernel.templateparser.TemplateNode and the method getSiblings() and getChildren() both methods return type is List only. But i find one difference that is- getChildren() method is putting Arraylist(group of objects) inside list. I am confused how to fetch the Arraylist from that list and after that we have to fetch values from the arraylist. Please help me on this.

Comment: Any one help me on this please?